# On the proof of Plancherel's Theorem in the Evans Book.

Tags: analysis, proof-explanation, lp-spaces, fourier-transform

If $u\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then its Furier transform is 
$
\hat{u}(y):=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2})}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-ix\cdot y}u(x) d x
$
and its inverse Fourier transform 
$
\check{u}:=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2})}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{ix\cdot y}u(x) d x.
$
Plancherel's theorem, as stated in the book by Evans, tells us that if $u\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then $\hat{u},\check{u}\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and 
$
\| \hat{u}\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}= \| \check{u}\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}=\|u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}.
$

[image]

> **First question.** In the first part of the demonstration (see figure below) why establish identity
>   $$
> \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2})}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \hat{w}(y)e^{-\epsilon |y|^2}u(x) d y
> =
> \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2})}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} w(y)e^{\frac{-|y|^2}{4\epsilon}}u(x) d x 
> \quad ?
> $$

[image]

> **Second question.** I suspect that in the second part of the proof (see figure below) can be concluded that $ \hat{u} \in L^2 (\mathbb{R}^n) $. How can I get this conclusion from the second part of the proof?

[image]

> **Third question.** In the second part of the demonstration it is concluded that $ \| \hat{u} \|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)} = \| u \|_{L^2 (\mathbb{R}^n)} $. How can I get this other conclusion from the second part of the demonstration?